# Mongomapper - bootstrapping techniques

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrapping, mongomapper

I've just begun creating a rails application using [mongomapper](http://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper) for my models. I'm wondering what solution should I use for bootstrapping my app with it.

All my previous experience is with ActiveRecord & PostgreSQL, in which I have used several gems for bootstrapping. The one I liked the most was [bootstrapper](http://github.com/sevenwire/bootstrapper) (+ [factorygirl](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) + [faker](http://faker.rubyforge.org/rdoc/)).

Does anyone know whether these work ok with mongomapper? Can anyone suggest better alternatives? Is there anything obvious I need to know when bootstrapping mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory_girl and faker works fine with MongoMapper.

So you can bootstrap your Rails app in the same way that before. Made some data in your db/seed.rb